# How to get a instance of the caller class in a static method in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

for example:

```
public class MyParentClass
{
  static MyParentClass AStaticMethod()
  {
    //get a new childclass instace here
    //modify this instance
    return(ChildClassInstance);
  }
}

public class AChildClass extends ParentClass {}
```

Is possible for `AStaticMethod` to get a new instace of the `AChildClass` when called from it (`AChildClass.AStaticMethod`)?

I've seen similar code using tricks like using the stack trace or throwing an exception and catching it, but I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Think of `AStaticMethod` as a generic initializer for child classes.

I remember that I did something like it in PHP, but it relied heavily on the dynamic weak typing and reflection of the language.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for a cleaner way to do
>   this.

There isn't any clean way to do this.

You should do some refactoring, like divide initializers and usage classes (like `AChildClass`) into separate classes.

Comment: I could, but then I would have to add my big initializer method to every child class only changing the class name, and repeat the process every time that some change is needed in the method. A true maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @user644718 You can deal with it using inheritance. Real reengineering solution depends from your program.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you *could* take an approach where you either wrap all your objects in a `dynamic proxy` or hook into the execution path using `AoP`. Whenever a method is invoked you could store this information in some static invocationLogging class. However, I see no *clean* way of achieving what you're asking.

---

You don't explicitly need to throw and catch an exception, you can just get it using

```
 StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

where the first element in the array should correspond to the last invoked method. E.g.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    first();
}

public static void first() {
    second();
}

public static void second() {
    StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    System.out.println(trace[0].getMethodName()); // getStackTrace
    System.out.println(trace[1].getMethodName()); // second
    System.out.println(trace[2].getMethodName()); // first
    System.out.println(trace[3].getMethodName()); // main
}
```

Comment: Attention: The actual contents of the `getStackTrace` is not guaranteed, they could let out elements, for example. So only use it for debugging, not for production use.